# Why is the spread operator needed to produce a return?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

Trying to figure out why the spread operator is needed in the code below in order for it to produce a return. When I delete the `...`, no return is produced.

```
function binaryAgent(str) {

  return String.fromCharCode(
    ...str.split(" ").map(function(char) {
      return parseInt(char, 2);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: The code is working for me without the spread operator

Comment: Because there's a difference between passing a single array parameter and passing separate parameters - [`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) expects the latter. Note `String.fromCharCode(NaN)` -> `'\x00'`, so that's what you get if you don't pass numbers.

Comment: @Tamir Abutbul: You get a difference by passing whitespace separated strings.

Comment: @jonrsharpe shouldn't this be an answer instead?

Comment: @BillyG  the comment of jonrsharpe and the reasoning why it's then a duplicate get's a bit more clear , if you first determine the intermediate array and save it in an extra variable: `const arr = str.split(" ").map(f);` and only then you want to spread the entries of this array into the arguments of the function  `String.fromCharCode()`, so you need the spread operator `String.fromCharCode(...arr)`